# Is the following happening because of closure or something else?

Tags: c#

Consider the below code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = Add(5, 5); // value 10
            var y = Add1(5, 5); // value 5  
        }

        static public int? Add(int? a, int? b)
        {
            a = a != null ? a : 0;
            b = b != null ? b : 0;
            return ( a+b );
        }

        static public int? Add1(int? a, int? b)
        {
            return (a != null ? a : 0 + b != null ? b : 0);
        }
```

Why is the discrepancy in result? Is it because of closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the language of the C# specification, this is because the additive `+` operator has a higher *precedence* than the conditional `?:` operator.

As per section 7.3.1 of the spec,

> When an expression contains multiple operators, the ***precedence*** of the operators controls the order in which the individual operators are evaluated. For example, the expression `x + y * z` is evaluated as `x + (y * z)` because the `*` operator has higher precedence than the binary `+` operator.

Thus

```
a != null ? a : 0 + b != null ? b : 0
```

is evaluated as

```
(a != null) ? a : (0 + ((b != null) ? b : 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

The second code:

```
return (a != null ? a : 0 + b != null ? b : 0);
```

Has a mistake in the `(<condition>) ? (<value1>) : (<value2>)` construct. If a is not null (and it's not, then the consuruction returns a, it  doesn't perform any addition).

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
return (a != null ? a : 0 + b != null ? b : 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a != null)
{
    return a;
} 
else 
{
    return b != null ? b : 0;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I seriously liked your answer because of a very clear explanation.but I have chosen the answer of Mr.Rawling for giving me more insight about the problem.Had there been a choice of accepting 2 answers , I would have chosen both.But I have up-voted u equally because that is in my hand.I hope you don't mind(:

Comment: Thank you for the comment - sure makes me feel better ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because if `a != null` simply `a` is returned by the ternary expression in `Add1`, the rest is not evaluated

Comment: The parenthesis have no effect here, if you leave them away it is exactly the same